# Remove custom post type slug from wordpress url

Tags: .htaccess, wordpress

My post URL is currently:

http://www.couponmartz.com/coupon/hellodemo-title

I want this URL to be like the following (without "**/coupon**"):

http://www.couponmartz.com/hellodemo-title.html

Is it possible removing it?

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score -2):

You need to check out the `register_post_type` function. There is a `$rewrite` variable you can set to `false` or pass some custom arguments.

Reference http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type

Comment: Most probably in your functions pho where your custom post type was registered

Comment: I have purchased theme from premiumpress.com
& there is nothing for register_post_type in functions.php file

Comment: Have you checked the theme folder of your purchased theme. It should be in `wp-content/themes/your-theme/functions.php` you should also check the included files if there is any.